# Woocommerce product file download URL

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am beginning to set up my commercial software on my website.

I have added the first one which is a simple woocommerce product that allows the user to do the usual 'add to cart'.

I also want to add a link that will allow the user to download the software as it is by default a demo. I have added this button but for the life of me, I find the woocommerce syntax to display the filename's download URL.

This is the current page: http://richardrosenman.com/shop/lens-corrector-pro/

You can see the "DOWNLOAD DEMO" button. But clicking on it will simply return the current product page which is most likely because I am using:

```
<?php echo esc_url( $product->product_url ); ?>
```

Can someone show me how to insert the product's file URL instead?

Any help would be appreciated as I am at a basic level with PHP.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use product meta data.
Please refer this link for more information

https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Meta_Data_Section